# JavaFX | How To Call Method To Draw Dots and Connect Lines

Tags: java, javafx, coordinates, lines

So I have a coordinate file that I have read and have created a loop that takes the coordinates from that file and reads each coordinate until the end and stores it into an array of objects/ point of objects. How would I call that method to draw my dots and then connect the lines without writing out every coordinate?

My code for loop and reading text file

```
try {

    // create the file reader instance
    FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    // create a scanner to scan through the file
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (fReader);


    // loop 
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int i = 0;
            int x = scan.next();
            int y = scan.next();
            Point[] = null;
            array[i] = point;

            i++;
        }


    // close the reader
        fReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's your draw method? Let's see what you've tried.

Comment: Are you using `Canvas` or `Nodes`?

Comment: draw line: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0040__JavaFX_Line.htm

Comment: draw circle: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0070__JavaFX_Circle_Arc.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of this

```
    //List for the dots
    ArrayList<Circle> dotList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // create the file reader instance
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        // create a scanner to scan through the file
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (fReader);

        // loop
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
            Circle dot = new Circle(x,y,10, Color.BLACK);
            dotList.add(dot);
            i++;
        }


        // close the reader
        fReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    Circle previousCircle = null;
    for (Circle circle : dotList)
        if (previousCircle != null) 
            new Line(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY(),
                previousCircle.getCenterX(), previousCircle.getCenterY());
        else previousCircle = circle;

    return 0;
}
```